How do you define universal and existential quantification rigorously and non-circularly?
Universal and existential quantification are necessary to build math from set theory. But I can't think of any way to define them besides the traditional intuition: that is, $(\forall x\in S)[p(x)]$ means "for all $x$ in $S, p(x)$" and $(\exists x\in S)[p(x)]$ means "there is some $x$ in $S$ such that $p(x)$". I know that one can define the other, but how can you rigorously define one of them? Obviously it will require axioms, but what would those axioms be?
It likely has to do with figuring out what $\forall$ and $\exists$ actually are. Functions can be defined as sets -- are $\forall$ and $\exists$ functions, taking in an input of two sets and returning a boolean value? Or does that make no sense? If so, then what type of mathematical structures are $\forall$ and $\exists$? And how can we use that to find axioms defining them?
Or are they indefinable? What would that even mean? I'm totally in the dark here -- can someone help?
Thanks for your patience!

They are grounded in natural language. They model in a formal and rigorous way how language works

What do you want to define them in terms of? Definitions have to be given in the context of an existing formal system. Usually, if we have $\forall$ and $\exists$, they are part of the underlying logic and so do not have a definition, just a set of axioms/re-write rules they must obey. You have to start somewhere, and this is part of where we start from, before we are ready to define anything else.

See quantification on nLab for some philosophical grounding.

You asked:

Obviously it will require axioms, but what would those axioms be?

I think what you are looking for is a formal exposition of first-order logic.  This defines:

The formal symbols of first-order logic and how they go together into formulas
The rules of inference: from some set of formulas, what other formulas can we conclude?
The interpretation of the formulas as talking about some set of mathematical objects

"First-order" here means roughly that the formulas can include $\forall x$ and $\exists x$, where $x$ must represent a single object from the domain of discourse. In "propositional logic" the $\forall$ and $\exists$ are absent; in "higher-order" logic one can have $\forall S$ and $\exists S$ where $S$ is a variable that represents an entire formula.
A typical rule of inference looks like this:
\begin{array}{c}
[t/x]A \\ \hline
(\exists x)[A]
\end{array}
The top half is the premise.  $A$ is a formula that may contain a variable $x$, and $[t/x]A$ is the result of replacing the variable $x$ with some term $t$.  The bottom half is the conclusion: $(\exists x)[A]$.  An example of this is that if we know that $$2\cdot2 = 2+2$$ then we can infer $$(\exists x)[x\cdot x=x+x].$$  Here $A$ is the formula $“x\cdot x=x+x”$ and $t$ is the term $“2”$. (I'm using your notation for quantified formulas.  More standard would be $“\exists x.x\cdot x=x+x”$.)  There are similar deductive rules that allow us to introduce formulas with $\forall$, and to eliminate $\exists$ and $\forall$ from formulas that contain them.  In some sense these rules of inference are the definition of the $\exists$ and $\forall$ quantifiers, since these rules completely capture how they behave in proofs. In this view $\forall$ and $\exists$ are not functions, they are formal symbols which can be manipulated in certain ways.
Item (3) in the list above is the domain of model theory. Model theory formalizes the idea that the formulas of logic are talking about something and that a formula may be true, or false, depending on what those somethings are.  For example, $“\exists x. x^2 = 2”$ is true if we are talking about the real numbers and false if we are talking about the integers, or about garden vegetables.
Peter Smith's book Beginning Mathematical Logic: A Study Guide covers these topics and may be helpful if you want to learn more. It can be downloaded for free, and inexpensive print copies are available.

The universal quantifier expresses generality: it has been formalized by Frege in order to express the difference between asserting that a statement holds in all instances and the assertion of one of the instances, without specifying which one.
See Universal instantiation.
The formal use of the symbol is defined by the syntactical specifications of the language.
The semantics gives rule for the evaluation of the truth value of a quantified statement. The rule states that a sentence $\forall x \varphi$ holds in an interpretation $M$ iff "... for every ..."
For Frege, quantifiers are higher-level concepts. A concept is higher level if it is “used to assert something of a concept”: specifically, the universal quantifier asserts that the quantified concept (predicate) holds for every instance.
See Quantifiers and Quantification.
